# Check if python class is defined in source code

Tags: python

Is there a simple way to check in python if a class is defined? Even if you know the location of the module file .py where the class should be defined.

Let's say I have these files, file1.py where I try to check if Class1 is defined in file2.py. And file3.py where I have a second class Class2 defined.

in file1.py, I have this code:

```
    try:
        modulePath = os.sep.join([cwd,os.sep.join(factory.split(".")[0:-1])]) + ".py"
        moduleName = factory.split(".")[-2]
        className = factory.split(".")[-1]
        m = imp.load_source(moduleName, modulePath)
        c = getattr(m, className)
    except:
        raise ValueError('Factory Path not correctly specified')
```

where

```
 factory = <string as path to the class 1> # for example com.Class1
 cwd = os.getcwd() # i.e. current working directory
```

in file2.py

```

```
from . import Class2

Class1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.object2 = Class2()
```

in file3.py

```

```
Class2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Basically, as the modules file2.py and file3.py are not installed, the code in file1 raise an error as imp can't find the Class2. I tried with and without relative import, without success...

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Do you have two python files? One that contains class(es) that you want to check exist?

Comment: how is imp not installed?

Comment: probably doesn't like the path you are trying to give it. Try using `os.path.abspath(".")` for the `cwd` value

Comment: and change your `except` to `except Exception, e:` to catch what the actual error is so we can have a better idea on what's happening

Answer (score 1):

If you know where the class resides and assuming the module containing the class is in the python path, then you can just wrap an import of that class in a `try` block

```
try:
    import MyClass
    #or
    from my_module import MyClass
except ImportError:
    #raise an exception or log a warning of some sort
```